# Installing Safeexec in Python Environment

Tags: python, sandbox

I am trying to use safeexec for a command execution. but i am not getting how to install it. I tried cloning this repo https://github.com/ochko/safeexec , but i am not able to install properly. can anyone please help me to do this?

I am not able to install this library.

Comment: What happened when you followed the installation instructions?